# How to provide path to node_modules to ant <exec> to run node

Tags: node.js, ant, node-modules

I want to make an ant target to run `nodejs` command, but I am not aware how can I provide the path to `node_modules` at run time. I am trying something like this.

```
<exec executable="${env.NODE_HOME}/node" >
    <env key="PATH" value="relative_path_to_node_modules}" />
    <arg value="parameter"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, needed to update environment variable NODE_PATH. In my opinion, node search for this particular env variable.